# overflow-y scroll isn't working in any browser

Tags: css, overflow

I tried to make masonry with CSS but the issue I am facing in `-webkit-column-width` is the overflow-y is not working. It always scrolls overflow-x.

```
#images {position: fixed; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 94%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: scroll; text-align: center; z-index: 2147483647; -webkit-column-width: 13em;-moz-column-gap: 1em;-webkit-column-gap: 1em;}
```

here is my complete code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gz787sxo/21/

Comment: please try to post the relavent piece of code here only.

Comment: please check my jsfiddle here:https://jsfiddle.net/gz787sxo/21/